# I want Search specific value in all columns of all tables in oracle 11g

Tags: search, oracle11g

Is it possible to search every field of every table for a particular value in Oracle.

I want to do it without using any procedure..

Can we do it with query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search All Fields In All Tables For A Specific Value (Oracle)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208493/search-all-fields-in-all-tables-for-a-specific-value-oracle)

Answer (score 12):

You can do it with a single query though it's a bit convoluted.  This query will search all CHAR and VARCHAR2 columns in the current schema for the string `'JONES'`

```
select table_name,
       column_name
  from( select table_name,
               column_name,
               to_number(
                 extractvalue(
                   xmltype(
                     dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
                       'select count(*) c from ' || table_name ||
                       ' where to_char(' || column_name || ') = ''JONES'''
                     )
                   ),
                   'ROWSET/ROW/C'
                 )
               ) cnt
          from (select utc.*, rownum
                  from user_tab_columns utc
                 where data_type in ('CHAR', 'VARCHAR2') ) )
 where cnt >= 0
```

Note that this is an adapted version of the Laurent Schneider's query to [count the rows in every table](http://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2007/04/how-do-i-store-the-counts-of-all-tables.html) with a single query.

Comment: Works like a charm on 10g also. But if you chage the last 'where cnt>=0' to 'cnt > 0', it gives an error. To overcome that, just wrap the entire query from an outer query, like this : 

select x.* from (ABOVE QUERY) where x.cnt > 0