# search data in oracle database

Tags: oracle

I am using oracle database and trying to search data in whole database. I know that value  'test' is stored in some tables but i dont know in which table,table column contain that value. So I want to write a query to search the whole database to find out the which table contains that 'test' string. any simplest solution. thanks

Comment: Can you please rewrite your question, it really makes no sense.

Comment: i dont know exactly which table contains the data. and i want to find out that.

Comment: Where's the link to the original?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208493/search-all-fields-in-all-tables-for-a-specific-value-oracle/5114486#5114486

Comment: http://www.mikerodey.com/oracle-pl-sql-search-string-all-tables