# Any way to search table name based on the content in the column of the table?

Tags: mysql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search All Fields In All Tables For A Specific Value (Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208493/search-all-fields-in-all-tables-for-a-specific-value-oracle)

Like we can search in the name of file and directory by the by content in the file in the unix using commands
same way  is there any query to search the name of the table based on the content in the column  in ORACLE or mysql ?

Comment: can you give some example?

Comment: what do you mean by `searching the name of file by content?`

Comment: @BhavikShah Thanks for replying...
like in Unix we can search as Grep -rl "data" /path
same way means you know just data but do not know the name of the column or table ...
so any query by which we can search the table and column name by data..

Comment: its possible to display all the columns but searching might not be possible or might be too complicated

Answer (score 0):

Directly from the database it might not be possible to find the tablename from the value in a particular column. However if you have the column name, you can find the tables which contain this column from `user_tab_cols` to narrow down your manual search.