# Find and replace, looped through all tables in oracle DB

Tags: database, oracle, loops, replace

I am trying to loop through every table in an oracle DB, and find and replace a string value.  I want to find all instances of a string value, replace it with another string value, for all entries in the entire DB.  I was close, but for some reason my code is not responding properly.

```
DECLARE
   CURSER all_tables IS
      SELECT table_name FROM all_tables;
   v_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
   FOR host IN all_tables LOOP
      SELECT REPLACE('jack','j','b') "Changes"
         FROM host
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Please show what you've done so far. This is possible, but it's a pretty unusual thing to do.

Comment: It's essentially the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208493/search-all-fields-in-all-tables-for-a-specific-value-oracle, except with update instead...

Comment: `CURSER` is an incorrect keyword, and you have to specify a column name instead of Jack. I don't understand why you wrote this code.

Comment: Looping through all columns in all tables is a useful technique. The chosen example is unusual, the general approach is worth learning.

Answer (score 3):

**A word of caution**

If you are actually trying to replace a string value for *every* column in *every* table in your schema, please be aware that it is going to take *hours*, at least.

Disclaimer aside, similar scripts turn out to be useful in a lot of situations (maybe to change a column name, maybe to perform massive data cleaning, or to create your tables from a metadata table).

**The general approach**

Basically, you need to:

1. Loop through every table in the target schema
2. For each table, loop through every `VARCHAR2` column
3. For each column, generate an `UPDATE` statement and execute it

A smarter solution generates only one `UPDATE` statement for each table. Your solutions will then:

1. Loop through every table in the target schema
2. For each table, generate the first part of the `UPDATE` statement up to the `SET` clause
3. For each column, append the part of the `SET` clause to your statement
4. Execute your statement

Example code for Oracle 10g/11g, using the well-known HR schema:

**One UPDATE statement per column**

```
DECLARE
    schemaName VARCHAR2(30) := 'HR';
    stmt VARCHAR2(32767); -- on 11g, use CLOB
BEGIN
    FOR tr IN (
        SELECT t.OWNER, t.TABLE_NAME
        FROM ALL_TABLES t
        WHERE t.OWNER = schemaName
        ORDER BY 1, 2
    )
    LOOP
        FOR cr IN (
            SELECT c.COLUMN_NAME
            FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS c
            WHERE c.OWNER = tr.OWNER AND c.TABLE_NAME = tr.TABLE_NAME
              AND c.DATA_TYPE = 'VARCHAR2'
            ORDER BY 1
        )
        LOOP
            stmt := 'UPDATE '||tr.OWNER||'.'||tr.TABLE_NAME
                ||' SET '||cr.COLUMN_NAME||' = REPLACE('||cr.COLUMN_NAME||', ''j'', ''b'')';
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stmt||';'); -- useful for debugging
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**One UPDATE statement per table**

You can try to be smarter and use only one `UPDATE` statement for all the columns in a table. Be careful not to overflow the `stmt` variable.

```
DECLARE
    schemaName VARCHAR2(30) := 'HR';
    stmt VARCHAR2(32767); -- on 11g, use CLOB
    do_update BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
    FOR tr IN (
        SELECT t.OWNER, t.TABLE_NAME
        FROM ALL_TABLES t
        WHERE t.OWNER = schemaName
        ORDER BY 1, 2
    )
    LOOP
        do_update := FALSE;
        stmt := 'UPDATE '||tr.OWNER||'.'||tr.TABLE_NAME||' SET ';
        FOR cr IN (
            SELECT c.COLUMN_NAME
            FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS c
            WHERE c.OWNER = tr.OWNER AND c.TABLE_NAME = tr.TABLE_NAME
              AND c.DATA_TYPE = 'VARCHAR2'
            ORDER BY 1
        )
        LOOP
            do_update := TRUE;
            stmt := stmt||cr.COLUMN_NAME||' = REPLACE('||cr.COLUMN_NAME||', ''j'', ''b''), ';
        END LOOP;
        IF do_update THEN
            stmt := SUBSTR(stmt, 1, LENGTH(stmt) - 2); -- remove trailing ', '
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stmt||';'); -- useful for debugging
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```