# query to find all tables which contains a particular test?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, grep

Is there any query to find all tables in oracle that contains a particular text?

similar to UNIX syntax `grep -rls 'text'`

I have used the query `select * from user_source where text like '%text%';` to find the text in packages.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208493/search-all-fields-in-all-tables-for-a-specific-value-oracle

Comment: `text`... you want to check for `text` value in column names or in data present in tables??