# How find value in all columns in an table (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, find

Need a script for quiqly find specific value in all columns of table.
Something like this dont work:

> select column name from table where value = 'value'

Comment: There's no trivial answer to this question. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208493/search-all-fields-in-all-tables-for-a-specific-value-oracle) that covers the same topic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search value in all tables of database Oracle 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591007/search-value-in-all-tables-of-database-oracle-10)