# Search inside content of all tables in a schema

Tags: sql, database, oracle, field, toad

Hi i have database with more than 400 tables, and i don't know how the data migration from application side to data warehouse this is a problem because i don't know where i can find a particular information in the database which table used ?
i am just asking is there a way to search for particular content of field in all the tables of schema ?

Comment: I dont know exactly what you want, but i think you can use system tables to find table schema.

Comment: You can, sure.  See the duplicate thread.  But be aware that it's going to be insanely slow.

Comment: See [SQL to Search for a VALUE in all COLUMNS of all TABLES in an entire SCHEMA](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/01/06/sql-to-search-for-a-value-in-all-columns-of-all-atbles-in-an-entire-schema/).

Comment: @LalitKumarB the query is not work with toad environment

Comment: @Nawaf What do you mean by toad environment? It is a client tool, not a database. Anyway, I see your question has been marked as duplicate, so you can find answers in the other link. Or look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208493/search-all-fields-in-all-tables-for-a-specific-value-oracle