# get an column name from the table by passing value in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want a query in oracle to get the column name from the table by passing value.
Means that In most of the case - We write the query like that -  **select * from table where column = 'value'.**  But in my case i don't know the column name.

Can any one suggest me.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: select * from user_tables

Comment: select table_name from user_Tables where table_name = 'school_master';

Comment: I have a value like 'Maria' and i want to search the column name and table name from the oracle database

Comment: You want to find the name of any column (in any table?) that contains that value? If so your question isn't clear; and [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/208493/266304).

Comment: Is 'Maria' a value contained in one or more of these unknown columns? How come you don't know the name of the column to look in? Is this some homework problem or something?

Comment: Yes,'Maria' is a value contained in one or more of these unknown columns.  Can you please help me for that

Comment: @MakDeveloper - try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208493/search-all-fields-in-all-tables-for-a-specific-value-oracle

Comment: If I understand your question. Its like you have a data and you have to search it throughout the database of each and evry table and list down the tale name and column name.

Comment: Yes, You are right.... Please help me for that

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build a dynamic query to check all the tables of your DB.

**setup:**

```
create table tab1 ( v1 varchar2(100), n1 number, v1b varchar2(100));
create table tab2 ( v2 varchar2(100), n2 number, v2b varchar2(100));
create table tab3 ( v3 varchar2(100), n3 number, v3b varchar2(100));
insert into tab1 values ('Maria', 1, 'aa');
insert into tab1 values ('xx', 2, 'bb');
insert into tab2 values ('yy', 3, 'Maria');
insert into tab2 values ('zz', 3, 'cc');
insert into tab3 values ('WW', 4, 'DD');
```

**build the dynamic query:**

```
select 'select table_name,
               matches from (' || listagg(statement, ' UNION ALL ') within group (order by table_name) || ')
        where matches > 0'
from (     
    select 'select ''' || table_name ||
             ''' as TABLE_NAME, count(1) as MATCHES from ' || table_name || ' WHERE ' ||
             listagg(column_name || ' = ''Maria''', ' OR ') within group (order by column_name) as statement,
            table_name
        from user_tab_columns col
        where data_type = 'VARCHAR2'
        group by table_name
     )
```

This will return a query, that you can run to check all the tables; in my example, this will build the query (not formatted) :

```
SELECT table_name, matches
  FROM (SELECT 'TAB1' AS TABLE_NAME, COUNT(1) AS MATCHES
          FROM TAB1
         WHERE    V1 = 'Maria'
               OR V1B = 'Maria'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'TAB2' AS TABLE_NAME, COUNT(1) AS MATCHES
          FROM TAB2
         WHERE    V2 = 'Maria'
               OR V2B = 'Maria'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'TAB3' AS TABLE_NAME, COUNT(1) AS MATCHES
          FROM TAB3
         WHERE    V3 = 'Maria'
               OR V3B = 'Maria')
 WHERE matches > 0;
```

Running this query will give:

```
TABL    MATCHES
---- ----------
TAB1          1
TAB2          1
```

Please notice that I used `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`, thus searching only in the tables of the login schema; if you want to search in different schemas, you can use `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` or `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS`, depending on what you need and on the privileges of you user; see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm#I1020277) for something more.

Also, consider that `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` will get the colums of tables and views; if you want to limit your search to tables, you can join `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`(`ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`, `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS`) to `USER_TABLES` (`ALL_TABLES`, `DBA_TABLES`) by `TABLE_NAME`, or `TABLE_NAME` and `OWNER` If you decide to use ALL or DBA tables:

```
SQL> create view vTab1 as select * from tab1;

View created.

SQL> select count(1)
  2  from user_tab_columns
  3  where table_name = 'VTAB1';

  COUNT(1)
----------
         3

SQL> select count(1)
  2  from user_tab_columns
  3       inner join user_tables using(table_name)
  4  where table_name = 'VTAB1';

  COUNT(1)
----------
         0

SQL>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select table_name from user_Tables where table_name = 'bogus';
```

Comment: I have a value like 'Maria' and i want to search the column name and table name from the oracle database

Comment: The OP is asking for a the column name given a value. Your answer does will just give them the table name which they already have.