# Identify and retrieve values of all varchar columns in a Oracle database

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following query that gives me a result set of all tables and columns in my Oracle database of `VARCHAR` columns:

```
SELECT ATC.OWNER, ATC.TABLE_NAME, ATC.COLUMN_NAME
FROM all_tab_columns ATC
WHERE DATA_TYPE LIKE '%VARCHAR%'
```

To this I want to add a 4th column that displays the value of ATC.COLUMN_NAME. Is there an easy way of doing this?

I thought of doing a join to a SQL statement that loops through ATC.COLUMN_NAME and outputting the value. The join would be done on the table name.

I don't know if I'm complicating it and I can't think of the SQL. I've tried declaring the above statement in a variable and then using a CTE to interrogate it but I would still need to loop through the table_name and column_name values.

Is there a simpler way?

Edit: Sample data

[image]

Comment: Say you have a table with a varchar2 column and 100 rows in the table. How mony output rows do you expect? 100 rows with the values in the table and the first 3 columns always with the same 3 values?

Comment: My query returns a unique column name for each table_name. So although the table_name will appear multiple times, the column_name and table_name row together will be unique

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and desired result to clarify your need?

Comment: @SSingh - The table name and column name can be unique, but what about the data in it ? how do you expect to see the data

Comment: OWNER TABLE  COLUMN                             Value
Owner Table 1 REMARKS                    blah, blah
Owner Table 1 RETURN_REMARKS    yes
Owner Table2 RETURN_REMARKS    No answer 
Owner Table2 REMARKS                    Tried calling
Owner Table 3 RETURN_REMARKS    Was in
Owner Table 3 MEETING_NOTES            Good meeting

Comment: Please add that to your question as formatted text, not as a comment (as it's basically unreadable...) You would have to do this dynamically, but it seems like an odd thing to want to do - kind of a pseudo-export. What do you plan to do with the results?

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL. There are lots of examples on this site of how to do that.

Comment: Alex - The database is large,the query above produces 14k rows approx. Sample data in the post now. I want to scan free text fields for certain patterns of data such as NI numbers for example to ensure GDPR compliance. While we have dedicated fields for such things unfortunatley users have also been referring to individuals in comments and notes fields. I have a REGEX query that correctly identifies the pattern but for ease  I wanted that output next to COLUMN_NAME

Comment: @SSingh - searching is bit different to just listing... [this shows how to search for a fixed value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/208493/266304), but that or APC's answer could be adapted to use a regular expression filter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use dynamic SQL. this is a proof of concept, it will not scale well when run against a large database.

```
declare
    stmt varchar2(32767);
    val varchar2(4000);
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    for r in ( SELECT ATC.OWNER, ATC.TABLE_NAME, ATC.COLUMN_NAME
               FROM all_tab_columns ATC
                WHERE DATA_TYPE LIKE '%VARCHAR%' )
    loop
        stmt := ' select distinct '|| r.column_name || 
                ' from '|| r.owner||'.'||r.table_name;
        open rc for stmt;
        loop
            fetch rc in val;
            exit when rc%notfound;
            dbms_output.put_line ( r.owner||'.'||r.table_name ||'.'|| r.column_name
                   ||': '|| val );
        end loop;
    end loop;
end;
```