# Find string and replace in whole database in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to replace '@flipkart.com' to '@Walmart.com' in whole database. I try to use all_tab_colums but this will not able to help to find the string in table.

Please assist.

Comment: Refer to this question. You might able to get an idea. - https://stackoverflow.com/q/208493/6327676

Comment: This Articale will not help.This will serach for column name instead of table data. I am looking for table data search.For example :If database has table emp_details and it has emil_id column containing data xyz@flipkart.com  then we need to replace it with xyz@walmart.com. This change required in whole database. Please assist

Comment: How come you don't know where you store your data? With a proper db design, you don't run into problems like this.