# How can I return a list of table names if a column of a table contains a specific value?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to return a list of all table names of a row in that table contains like specific value "%searchString%"

I have seen similar questions in the form but couldn't fine one related to oracle database "i am using sqldeveloper to connect". I am not an expert to know how to map the script from one environment to another.

I am able to get the list of all available tables by

```
SELECT table_name FROM all_tables
```

And I am able to get the list of all column names for a specific table by

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='tableName'
```

Pseudo Code

```
result = [] #empty list
searchString = "desiredString"
tableNames = getTableNames() #all tables in DB
for (int i = 0; i < tableNames.length; i++){
    match = false
    tableRows = # list containing all rows of that table
    columnNames = # list of all column names of that table
    for (int j = 0; j< tableRows.length; j++){
        for (int k = 0; k<columnName.length ; k++){
            if(tableNames[i].tableRows[j].columnNames[k].value.contains(searchString)){
                match = true
                break
            }
        if (match == true) break
    }
if(match == true) result.append(tableNames[i])
}
print result
```

Thanks to comments below, I was able to combine some solutions and it is working fine as below

```
variable val varchar2(255)
exec :val := 'oldDomain.com'

WITH  char_cols AS
  (SELECT /*+materialize */ table_name, column_name
   FROM   cols
   WHERE  data_type IN ('CHAR', 'VARCHAR2'))
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR (:val, 1, 11) "Searchword",
       SUBSTR (table_name, 1, 14) "Table",
       SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 14) "Column"
FROM   char_cols,
       TABLE (xmlsequence (dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype ('select "'
       || column_name
       || '" from "'
       || table_name
       || '" where upper("'
       || column_name
       || '") like upper(''%'
       || :val
       || '%'')' ).extract ('ROWSET/ROW/*') ) ) t
ORDER  BY "Table"
/
```

ok the idea is I want to replace this value for a new one.

let's say that I want to replace "oldDomain.com" to "newDomain.com"

Comment: One of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/208493/266304) should give you some ideas. You only want the table names, not the column names too?

Comment: @AlexPoole yes, I only want the table names