# oracle sql query to find email address across all schemas

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, recursive-query

I am trying to identify all the tables and columns across Database schemas with a search pattern '@abc.de' , ideally this exercise is to

1. identify the specific table and associated columns using email patterns (@abc.de)
2. pickup that list and cross verify whether the email address are valid or not

unfortunately the point 1 is very difficult

upon searching and trying to find

[Search All Fields In All Tables For A Specific Value (Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208493/search-all-fields-in-all-tables-for-a-specific-value-oracle)

**SQL CODE**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
    l_cmd     VARCHAR2 (2000);
    l_found   INTEGER;
BEGIN
    FOR eachcol IN (  SELECT *
                        FROM all_tab_cols a
                       WHERE a.data_type = 'VARCHAR2'
                        AND owner = 'schema_name'
                    ORDER BY table_name, column_name)
    LOOP
        l_cmd   :=
               'select count(*) c from '
            || eachcol.owner
            || '.'
            || eachcol.table_name
            || ' where '
            || LOWER (eachcol.column_name)
            || q'[ LIKE '%@abc%.de%' AND ROWNUM = 1]';

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_cmd INTO l_found;

        IF l_found > 0
        THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
                   RPAD (eachcol.owner || '.' || eachcol.table_name || '.' || eachcol.column_name, 92)
                || ' may contain email addresses'
            );
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_cmd);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);
        RAISE;
END;
```

I am getting the below error

```
Error report -
ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06512: at line 35
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual.
```

Note : I have tried many options to fetch the email address but not getting the right query logic , any suggestions ?

Comment: In most systems I have worked on, looping through every single `varchar2` column in the schema one at a time would take more than a human lifetime. Are there really no clues in the column names? You might also exclude columns too small to be an email address - presumably `a@b.cd` is about the smallest an email address can be, so you are looking for  6 characters or more for a start.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - I can definately refine by specifying the required columns ,but to ensure to identify all the emails across the DWH schemas ,but realisticayllt seems difficult and consumes lot of time and query never ends and retruns numerious errors, i will see if can find columns

Answer (score 2):

Remove useless `WHEN OTHERS` exception. It hides exact error point as line #35 is `RAISE`.

Then, display table and column name you're currently working with - use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` for that, placed right behind `LOOP`.

Once you hit the error, procedure will stop and display the last table/column which raised the error. I *presume* that it is something like this:

```
SQL> create table xxx ("!what ?" varchar2(10));

Table created.
```

Your code ends up with

```
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression
ORA-06512: at line 35
```

which isn't exactly what you got, but - you'll find it out yourself. I can't, I don't have your tables.

Comment: it's not working can you please update in the code ? i am running into other errors