# Can we search a string value in all tables of oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string value that i need to search in my oracle db with inside all table's columns.
Is there any way to search the value in all tables?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search All Fields In All Tables For A Specific Value (Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208493/search-all-fields-in-all-tables-for-a-specific-value-oracle)

Comment: WHY do you need that? I have seen such questions before; I never heard a good reason for it.